# What exactly makes reaction turbines work?

Tags: turbines

I was reading about reaction turbines on Wikipedia, it says: "*Reaction turbines develop torque by reacting to the gas or fluid's pressure or mass. The pressure of the gas or fluid changes as it passes through the turbine rotor blades.*"

I understand the working of impulse turbine by utilisation of kinetic energy, but this confuses me. Can anybody explain?

Comment: Reaction turbines work by changing the *direction* of the fluid flow as it passes through the turbine, not by changing the flow velocity. Newton's 2nd law: force = rate of change or momentum.

Comment: And how does the fluid pressure drops in a turbine?